# What is the best solution to do Reporting on Object data for .NET?

Tags: asp.net, oop, reporting, product

Our projects are using objects as the data source to reports.

Our business layer is returning single objects or IEnumerable. Our reports (quite complex) need to display value-type properties of the object, and its related objects.
Typical case would be, from a List, display a master report with category data, then a subreport with data for each Product inside each Category, then a subreport for each Part of each Product, and so on.

Reporting from the database is not an option for us.

We have tried so far
- Reporting Services : works but have to mess around with the XML definition of the report to define the datasource classes, very hard to work with if you use an object datasource, architecturally not too clean
- Telerik Reports : quite nice (esp., nice architecture) but seems to have problems with complex reports (master/sub), does not give great paging control, rumored to have performance/crash problems (immature product).

Does anyone know a good reporting solution that can be integrated in an ASP.NET application and works well with objects as datasources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using ActiveReports and XtraReports. I have experience with Telerik Reports too.
The XtraReports and Telerik Reports are one of the best reporting tools, which are available. I haven't any problems with master/detail reports with and with with hierarchical data too. But XtraReports and Telerik Reports has very good oficial support. If you have any problem with their components, they typicaly provides solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being able to bind a report to a collection of objects (see IListDataSource), you can also have even greater control of the data binding with [ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ProductOverview.aspx?Product=ARNET3) unbound mode. See the following for more info about unbound mode in ActiveReports: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ARNET3/ActiveReports3_start.htm